# Thread.sleep() работает не так, как надо

Tags: java

Пишу пошаговую 2D игру, где персонаж передвигается в строго заданном направлении по клеткам поля. Использую `MouseListener`. При нажатии правой кнопки мыши вызывается метод `pressRightButton()` из класса `Game`(game - объект класса Game, в котором описаны методы, отвечающие за передвижение персонажа), который отвечает за определенную последовательность действий: в данном случае совершает 2 шага вперед, с задержкой между шагами 2 секунды.

Вопрос состоит в том, что при нажатии правой кнопки мыши первым делом выполняется задержка в 2 секунды, а затем 2 раза выполняется метод `moveForward()` без всякой задержки между ними. Почему так происходит и как сделать так, чтобы задержка происходила между методами?

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
            game.pressRightButton();
    }
}
```

Метод `pressRightButton()`:

```
public void pressRightButton() {
    moveForward();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { };
    moveForward();
}
```

Comment: попробуйте все в `pressRightButton` поместить в `try catch`. Второй метод сработает сразу если `sleep` кинет эксепшн

Comment: У вас неверная логика работы. Вам даже нужно добавить ещё один поток в приложение. И уже в нём производить передвижение.